# How to pass 64 long integer through JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I tried to pass 1000, 1000000 as long (java) and (long long) c++, it works fine. But I tried to pass this number 549755813888, in jni this number shows as zero. I dont know how to pass it into native part.

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL myMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass type,jlong mynum) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "SDK", "mynum %d", mynum);
    //Shows zero
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `jlong` actualy is `long long` so use `"mynum %lli"`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty skimpy on specifics.  But since 549755813888 is 0x1000000000, it sure looks like you are calling a method using a jint instead of a jlong or somewhere along the line truncating long long to int.  Your code should be something like:

```
jlong jLongValue = 549755813888LL;
env->CallObjectMethodV(obj, methodData->mid, jLongValue);
```

And make sure that the method being called actually takes a long not int?

Comment: What is method->mid? When I set "(J)V" to methodDat my app is down.

Comment: The JNI invocation API requires a "method ID" which you would have looked up by name from the class.  You really need to post some code.  From your question I can't tell if you are calling Java from C++ or the other way around.

Comment: I call native method public static final native long Mymethod( long mynum);
in jni jlong mymethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jlong mynum)
When I try log mynum its show zero

Comment: You are probably getting the right value, but you need to use %ld not %d in your format, assuming that __android_log_print uses printf standard format.

Comment: I use %ld in all log prints.

Comment: No, you don't.  From your code snippet:     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "SDK", "mynum %d", mynum);